# Composer with satis invalid credentials in a Windows Server

Tags: php, git, composer-php, satis

*First: sorry for my english, if anyone can edit the question for me.*

I'm trying to create a server with satis/composer.

For do that I install composer/statis/git/svn/apache/php/openssl in a Windows Server 2012.

Then I add/edit/create some configurations but composer request an authentication and I don't know why because, accessing web browser, satis display all the packages normally.

**my config.json**

[image: config.json]

**Error:**

[image: invalid credentials]

Informations:

- In the network

  - Has a proxy
  - Has a firewall
- All computers/notebooks are Windows 7
- Composer, Git, Svn are updated

---

If anyone needs more information leave a comment please.

Comment: Can you curl `http://10.33.6.48:99/satis/packages.json` from the machine trying to run composer? Or generally access that file outside of composer?

Comment: Oh dear... HTTP 403. Proxy right?

Comment: Well 403 = forbidden which matched the composer error. You can add `options` to the `repositories` config such as in [this composer doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#security) but I'm not sure what exactly to use for your situation. I would recommend identifying how to provide credentials on a curl command or similar while you're debugging this

Comment: Eh just realized that link was about adding options to the config for satis, not the config for your composer project. But I think there's something similar

Comment: [This is what I should have linked](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#stream-options)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I identify the problem executing the `curl` command and the return is **forbidden**.

Then I just test the same command without company proxy and works, so that is the problem.

Now, it's works.

Thanks guys.